# Particle Info Node with several Particle systems

Tags: node-editor, particles

Let's say I have three particle systems in my scene.
Is there a way of accessing the properties of each individual particle system using the Particle Info Node?
Or can the Particle Info Node only be used when one single particle system exists in the project?

Kind Regards
Ryosei

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:
In my case The Particle Info Node attaches to a material setup for the instanced mesh object used in one of the Particle systems. Therefore the Particle Info Node can only be relevant for that particular particle system.